# Copy specific items in one CSV and paste them n amount of times into another CSV

Tags: python, linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I'm trying to accomplish something that might seem rather simple but it's giving me a really hard time.

I have two CSVs:

```
file1.csv
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3
item1,  item4,  item7
item2,  item5,  item8
item3,  item6,  item9 

file2.csv
HEADER1, HEADER2
item1,   item3
item1,   item3
item1,   item3
item1,   item3
item2,   item3
item2,   item3
```

I would like to copy item7 from file1.csv the same number of times that item1 in file2.csv exists (this can be any number of times), do the same for item8 in file1.csv and item2 in file2.csv and concatenate the results into a new file. The resulting file should look like this:

```
file3.csv
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3
item1,   item2,   item7
item1,   item2,   item7
item1,   item2,   item7
item1,   item2,   item7
item2,   item2,   item8
item2,   item2,   item8
```

I would be extremely thankful if someone could give me hand with this. I don't really care about the method/tool as long as the result looks like my example.

Comment: You can do it with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Should the second column in the output really be item2? Or did you mean item3?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It should be item3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the records are not sorted `awk` can handle with ease.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3; next} 
                            {print $0,a[$1]}' file1 file2

HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item2,   item3,  item8
item2,   item3,  item8
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your output's second column is supposed to be `item3`, not `item2`, and your actual file is sorted like your example is (A requirement for `join`), and that you're using the GNU version of [`join(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)to get the `--header` option:

```
$ join -t, --header -j1 -o 0,2.2,1.3 file1.csv file2.csv
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item1,   item3,  item7
item2,   item3,  item8
item2,   item3,  item8
```

Comment: `-j1` doesn't need to be specified explicitly since it's the default.